# Weird Behavior while inserting a character into string in C++

Tags: c++, string, insert

I was trying to insert a character in string in C++ by insert method and following is my code but it does not seem to work out. I does not know exact reason why this is happening?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string func1(int n)
{
    string answer;
        bitset<1000> bits(n);
        bool b=false;
        if(ceil((double)log2(n/1.0))>=2)
            b=true;
    for(int i=ceil((double)log2(n/1.0));i>=2;i--)
    {
        b=true;
        if(bits.test(i)==true)
            answer+="2("+func1(i)+")+";
    }
    //answer+=")";
    if(bits.test(1)==true)
            answer+="2";
    if(bits.test(0)==true)
            answer+="2(0)";
    return answer;
}

int main()
{
    string s1=func1(1315);
    string answer;
        cout << s1 << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<s1.length()-4;i++)
    {

       if(s1.substr(i,4)=="2(0)" && s1.at(i-1)!='+')
        s1.insert(i-1,1,'+');
    }
    cout << s1 << endl;

}
```

Comment: First time round your loop `i-1` is -1, so `at()` will throw an [out_of_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/) exception.

Comment: Merely inserting a character is as simple as calling`insert`, but you're doing a lot more than that.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish with all of that code?

Comment: *but it does not seem to work out* -- If the first comment is correct, and you were getting an `out_of_range` exception, why didn't you mention this in your question?

Comment: Your code [produces this output](http://ideone.com/qUe4kU).  So with all of that code, and the output produced, you need to state exactly what you expected as output, and better yet, what is the high-level goal of all of this code?  I won't be surprised if there is a much simpler solution to whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish but your code has a few logical bugs.

Perhaps you intended to do `s1.substr(i, 4)` instead of `s1.substr(i, i+4)`. The second argument of `substr` is length.

Even after doing this you might enter infinite loop because the length of the string is increasing by 1 every-time you insert and you recheck from the same index.

This should be logically more correct than your code:

```
for(int i=0;i<s1.length()-4;i++)
{
   if(i>0 && s1.substr(i,4)=="2(0)" && s1.at(i-1)!='+')
     s1.insert(i-1,1,'+');
   i++;
}
```